# Bootstrap vue table not getting updated when data added from another component in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I am using bootstrap vue table to display server data.Page is updated on created method alone.My component structure is like below.
1) AddingData.vue
2) table.vue

So in addingData component, i am having a button .When i click that , it should go /1 route and display table.After that if i add another data, it is not getting updated.If i use updated method,it is getting updated.But spoils other route..how to make it reactive?

```
created() {
       this.loadData();
  },

   methods: {

    loadData() {
      let promise = axios.get('/urls/'+this.$route.params.id+'/')

      return promise.then((data) => {
        this.serverData = data.data.results;
        this.currentPage = parseInt(this.$route.params.id);
        this.totalPage = data.data.total_pages;   
        this.previousPage = data.data.previous;
        this.nextPage = data.data.next;
        this.page_no = data.data.current_page_no;
        this.navigation=false;
        if (this.currentPage == 1) {
          $('#first').addClass('disabled');
        }

        if (this.currentPage == this.totalPage) {
          $('#last').addClass('disabled');
        }
        if (this.previousPage == false) {
          $('#previ_btn').addClass('disabled');
        }
        if (this.nextPage == false) {
          $('#next_btn').addClass('disabled');

       }

      }).catch(error => {

              return []
              this.$router.push({name:'service',params:{id:1}});


      })

    },
```